# Is it possible to echo a jQuery-function from php?

Tags: php, jquery, echo

I need to load content into a div using a php-script triggered in another div but I'm at my wit's end..

Something like this:

`echo"<script>$('#posters').load($query->execute($sql));</script>";`

Comment: Try looking into $.get http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this?

This gets a php file (sql-query.php) in and then changes the content in the div #update upon a button click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn').click(function(){
       $.get("sql-query.php", function (result) {
         $('#update').html(result);
       });
    });
});
```